# OpenSSL in Qt5 on Windows

Tags: c++, openssl, qt5

I'm trying to link openssl with qt5.12 but the result differs when running executable from qt and from command line. I use QSslSocket::supportsSsl(), QSslSocket::sslLibraryVersionString() and QSslSocket::sslLibraryBuildVersionString() to observe the results. When running exe from qt i get the following output respectively `true` `OpenSSL 1.1.1d  10 Sep 2019` `OpenSSL 1.1.1k  25 Mar 2021` and for command line `false` `""` `OpenSSL 1.1.1k  25 Mar 2021`. The exe is compiled with msvc 2017 64 bit. What could be the problem and where does qt get that library from?

Comment: Use tools like Dependency Walker and/or Process Hacker 2/Process Explorer to find out what is loaded and why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using listdlls tool i managed to find the name and location of openssl DLLs. They're `libssl-1_1-x64.dll` and `libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll` and located in `%QT_INSTALL_PATH%/Tools/QtCreator/bin`. Copying those DLLs to the build folder of the project solved the issue.

QtCreator used build environment which is apparently the default environment and can be found in `Projects -> Run`. It sets a number of environment variables, and in my case exactly, it updated the `PATH` variable adding the path of QtCreator bin folder.

Answer (score 0):

Qt doesn't ship SSL libraries by default, you need to install them manually, to be sure that you have compatible SSL libraries Install `OpenSSL XXX Toolkit` from **Qt Maintenance Tool** then in `<Qt directory>/Tools/OpenSSL` you will find your OpenSSL packages with binaries.
[image]

In order to fully ship Windows Qt application to the end-users, please study https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-deployment.html closely